# Unable to build F# project by using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#

### Unable to build F# project via Visual Studio 2019

### My stuff:

Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.2)

from dotnet --info

```
Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.19041
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x64
Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\

.NET SDKs installed:
2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Project information:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

FSharp.Core version="5.0.0"
```

Problem:
When I trying to build a project by using Visual Studio I got an error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB6004 The specified task executable location "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\fsharp\dotnet" is invalid. MyProjectName   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\fsharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets    281
```

#### Additional info:

build by using CLI works fine (dotnet --version 5.0.100)
Microsoft.FSharp.Targets file is default
Visual Studio and SDK reinstalled a couple of times already

There is also an issue on the MS https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10515

After the latest update of Visual Studio (.net 5 update) I unable to build F# projects. Does someone have a similar problem?